# Lingua::Translate perl module raise an error while execute

Tags: perl

We've installed Lingua::Translate and used it as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Lingua::Translate;
my $trans = Lingua::Translate->new
                 (back_end => 'Babelfish',
                   src => "en",
                  dest => "it",);
print $trans->translate("Hello world");
```

Excuting this results in the following error:

```
Translation back-end failed; Request timed out more than 2 times (Request 1:301 Moved Permanently; Request 2:301 Moved Permanently; Request 3:301 Moved Permanently; ) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Lingua/Translate/Babelfish.pm line 206.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that this has to do with the fact that http://babelfish.yahoo.com/ now redirects to http://www.microsofttranslator.com/. I have no idea whether the underlying engine has changed. I would check CPAN to see if there's an updated version of Lingua::Translate, or check the perldoc to see if the URL is configurable within a given back end.

This has happened before: see [this bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=36076).

Based on that patch, it looks like you may be able to add babelfish_uri as one of the hash elements passed to Lingua::Translate->new(). This isn't in the documentation, it's just an educated guess.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternate method for language translation like this?